# How to show caret in a disabled MFC CEdit control?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, cedit

If an edit control is disabled, the caret disappears. that case, if the edit is displaying a long text, then it is not possible to see the rest of the words.With the caret i, we can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must use an enabled readonly edit control instead of a disabled one.

Check 'readonly' in the edit box property window or use `ES_READONLY` when calling `Create`.
Also, don't forget to check *Auto HScroll* (`ES_AUTOHSCROLL`) ( and *AutoVScroll* if multiline).

```
CEdit* pEdit = new CEdit;
pEdit->Create(ES_MULTILINE | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER
  | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY, (10, 10, 100, 100), this, 1);
```